# PHP count multiple files upload always return 1

Tags: php

Counting files when multiple upload with php and krajee fileinput plugin, my count variable return 1 no matter upload two files or more. Code below upload multiple files successfully, but the count isn't working.

```
if(isset($_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'])){
   $total = count(array_filter($_FILES['my_file']['name']));
   for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
     $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
     if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
       $newFilePath = "upload/" . $SN ."/" . $_FILES['my_file']['name'][$i];
       if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
             echo json_encode(array('id' => 'message', 'data' => 'success'));
           }
       }
   }
}

else {
 echo json_encode(array('id' => 'message', 'data' => 'fail'));
}
```

`$total = count(array_filter($_FILES['my_file']['name']));` always return 1 , but multiple files upload is working.

how to fix it , have to get correct number of files to rename them.

Answer (score 2):

You're counting the wrong `Array`.

"The global $_FILES will contain all the uploaded file information..." ([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)), with one row for each file uploaded.

Change your `for` loop to operate on the correct count using `foreach`:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
    $tmpFilePath = $file['tmp_name']; // change all references from $_FILES['my_file'] to $file
// ...
```